# Error with using argv with function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm beginning to learn cpp and I've started with a a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include "functions.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char * argv[]){
  double start=0;
  double end=0;
  vector<double> fbseq;

  getInput(argc,argv);

return 0;
}
```

and in functions.h, I have:

```
using namespace std;
void getInput(int,char **);
```

When I compile and run I get:

```
g++ fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci
/tmp/ccZ1cCvi.o: In function `main':
fibonacci.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `getInput(int, char**)'
```

I don't really understand what this means, can someone help me as I can see this is related to me not understanding pointers?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: You shouldn't put `using namespace std;` into a header file...

Comment: If I don't do that I get the following error when compiling: `g++ fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci
In file included from fibonacci.cpp:3:
functions.h:5: error: âvectorâ was not declared in this scope
functions.h:5: error: expected primary-expression before âintâ
`

Comment: You should refer to it at `std::vector` in the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a linker error, which means that the code compiles fine but the linker can't find the definitions for everything you've used. In this case, it means you haven't defined `getInput` anywhere. You need to give the function a body. Typically, you should do this in a corresponding `.cpp` file:

```
#include "functions.h"

void getInput(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Implement here
}
```

When you do have that, you need to make sure that you compile that file too. Just add it to the `g++` command.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not about pointers, it is about you only declared the function getInput and it is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your compilation command seems to miss functions.cpp or other file which implements getInput function.

P.S. You shouldn't write "using namespace std;" in header file, it's a bad practice. See Item 59 in Sutter and Alexandrescu's "C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices":

> "Don’t write namespace usings in a header file or before an #include."

Answer (score 0):

You have only declared `getInput` function (which is the part in the header file) but you have not actually defined it anywhere (specifying the function body).